# Remove all space on input text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

here is my html:

```
<input class="form" type="text" placeholder="test" />
```

and my JS

```
var str = $(".form").val();
var newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

there is no space when user input text. How to I create the javascript? anybody help? Thank you

Comment: you can use `.trim()`

Comment: So you want to prevent spaces or trim out the spaces?

Comment: Use the string method `.trim()`. What you're doing is removing ALL the spaces in the string.

Comment: oh thank you. Yes I want remove all spacing

Comment: `var newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');` should do what you want

Comment: Are you asking how to update the input element to remove spaces? Because the code you've already shown will remove spaces from the value and put the result in `newStr`, so it's not clear what you think is missing.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes all space.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove starting and ending spaces use [`trim()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

```js
var value  = "  some text to trim  ";


console.log(value.trim());
```

If you want to remove all the spaces in entire string use replace

```js
var value = "Some text to replace spaces";
var newStr = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
console.log(newStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how to remove all space? the result to be "sometexttotrim()"

Comment: second example does that @dediwibisono

Comment: isnt this the same as the OP's?